# Add new providers to satellizer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, satellizer

I need to use 3 google satellizer providers, but each needs to have different scopes.

Is there a way to do that with the current lib, or I need to add them into satallizer core?

I would need something like:

```
$authProvider.google1({
  clientID: '',
  scope: [some scopes]
})

$authProvider.google2({
  clientID: '',
  scope: [some scopes]
})

$authProvider.google3({
  clientID: '',
  scope: [some scopes]
})
```

Or is there a way to add scopes at runtime?